# Sie (you - formal), sie (she) and sie (they) / Ihr (you - plural), er (he)

Tags: pronunciation, personal-pronoun

How to differentiate pronunciation of these words?

> - Sie (you — formal), sie (she), and sie (they)
> - ihr (you — plural), er (he)

Comment: In German you have always to consider the context. You can't distinguish the different "Sie" by pronunciation

Comment: @infinitesimalLeanne: "Sie machen das Heim zum Daheim", how one could differentiate they're talking about a person in formal sense or more than one person (plural)?

Comment: @Gigili: you can't. You need to know who that sentence is addressed at and/or what the context of that sentence is. It could be "you" (singular), "you" (plural) or even "they".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Sie* is always pronounced the same.

The pronunciation of *ihr* and *er* really only differs in the starting vowel — although the *h* demands the long pronunciation of *i*, the *e* of *er* is equally long.

Comment: Was about to make matters more complicated - but this answer is already all you need, so +1.